# How does this for loop work?  for ( ; i < length; i++ )

Tags: javascript, loops

How does this for loop work? It doesn't make sense to me.

```
for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
```

Answer (score 15):

The loop will simply repeat as long as `i` is less than `length`.  It simply assumes `i` is already declared elsewhere.

Actually, all parts within a `for` loop construct are optional.  For example, this is a perfectly valid way to create an endless loop:

```
​for(;;) window.alert('Are you sick of alerts yet?');​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: +1 for `for (;;)`, that brings back memories from before I realized `while (true)` was more legible (for some reason, I was introduced to `for (;;)` as the canonical way to create an infinite loop)...

Comment: Yea, JavaScript is a unique language in that these sorts of hacky-ish shortcuts are somewhat *encouraged* just to save bytes over the wire.  Otherwise, `while(true)` is for sure easier to read.  Casting with `!!` or `~~` is also fun..

Comment: Hah, but I was actually learning C++ at the time (first programming language), not JavaScript! ;-)

Answer (score 9):

It's a regular `for` loop that does nothing at all in the initialization step.

This is equivalent to writing:

```
;
while (i < length) {
    // ...
    i++;
}
```

except if there's a `continue` in the `...` body, in which case the `for` loop would execute the `i++` before re-evaluating the condition, and the `while` loop would not.

Comment: So why would one prefer writing this over a simple `while` loop ?

Comment: @nl-x: Good point. It's more compact, though slightly less readable; however, if the *intent* is to have a normal `for` loop, and there just happens to be no initialization step required, then I see nothing wrong with using that form. The real difference arises if there's a `continue` within the loop body -- the `for` form increments, but the `while` form does not. I've edited my answer to reflect this, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was not looking clearly. I thought the `i++` part was also omitted, eg `for (;i<length;)` My questions is why would that be prefered over writing a simple `while (i<length)` ? I have seen this contraption in the jquery library for example.

Comment: @nl-x: Hmm, beats me!